# Extract a portion of string from another string using regex

Tags: python

Lets assume I have a string as follows:

```
 s = '23092020_indent.xlsx'
```

I want to extract only `indent` from the above string. Now there are many approaches:

```
#Via re.split() operation
s_f = re.split('_ |. ',s) <---This is returning 's' ONLY. Not the desired output

#Via re.findall() operation
s_f = re.findall(r'[^A-Za-z]',s,re.I) 
s_f
['i','n','d','e','n','t','x','l','s','x']  
s_f = ''.join(s_f) <----This is returning 'indentxlsx'. Not the desired output
```

Am I missing out anything? Or do I need to use `regex` at all?

P.S. In the whole part of `s` only '.'delimiter would be constant. Rests all delimiter can be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `os.path.splitext` and then `str.split`:

```
import os
name, ext = os.path.splitext(s)
name.split("_")[1] # If the position is always fixed
```

Output:

```
"indent"
```

Comment: Instead of [:-1] it should be [1] isn't it?

Comment: @pythondumb Not really. In case of nothing to split, `name.split("_")[1]` may cause an `IndexError`, whereas `name.split("_")[-1]` will fall back to whatever the `name` was. Try with an example case like `23092020.xlsx`.

Comment: `indent` is the key word. hence it would be there for sure. Also if I have a multiple delimiter then the method you have shown would not suffice. E.g. `23092020_indent_archive.pdf`

Comment: @pythondumb Yes it will not work, and so is the regex. If you are always sure about the position of `"indent"`, indexing is the best way ;). I've edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I LOVE regex's, so that's definitely the way I'd go.

The exactly right answer requires more information as to all possible input strings and what the right thing to extract is for each of them.  Here's a solution that assumes:

1. one or more digits, then
2. a single underscore, then
3. a group of chars not containing a '.', then
4. a '.', then
5. anything besides a '.', but at least one char

The #3 part is captured.

```
import re

s = '23092020_indent.xlsx'

exp = re.compile(r"^\d+_(.*?)\.[^.]+$")
m = exp.match(s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

Result:

```
indent
```